# How to compare elements from an XML and add new node with 3 or more possible results using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an XML list of products and I need to assign weight on a new node to every product based on the category of each product. For example:

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 1</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 1</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 2</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 2</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 3</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 3</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 4</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 4</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 5</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 5</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 6</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 6</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 7</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 7</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 8</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 8</category>
  </item>
</products>
```

I have tried using this code using my logic, but is not working:

```
<?php

//CODE...

$weight = $xml->xpath("//item[category]");
foreach ( $weight as $value )    {
    $value->weight = ($value->category=='CATEGORY 1' or $value->category=='CATEGORY 2' or $value->category=='CATEGORY 3')? 1:2 and ($value->category=='CATEGORY 4' or $value->category=='CATEGORY 5')? 7:2 and ($value->category=='CATEGORY 6' or $value->category=='CATEGORY 7')? 10:2;
}

//MORE CODE...

?>
```

As you can see I have been trying to assign a weight of "1 Kg" if the products are on the categories 1, 2 and 3, "7 Kg" if they are on categories 4 and 5 and finally "10 Kg" if they are on categories 6 and 7 but if they don't match any of that categories set the weight to "2 Kg" to get a result similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 1</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 1</category>
    <weight>1</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 2</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 2</category>
    <weight>1</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 3</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 3</category>
    <weight>1</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 4</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 4</category>
    <weight>7</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 5</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 5</category>
    <weight>7</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 6</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 6</category>
    <weight>10</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 7</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 7</category>
    <weight>10</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 8</name>
    <category>CATEGORY 8</category>
    <weight>2</weight>
  </item>
</products>
```

I have the feeling that this is pretty simple but my logic has not yielded results. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when using such long chained ternary operators as there can be problems with the order in which it gets evaluated.  I would do two things, first is to extract just the last character and then just build the condition based on that.  The second is to use brackets round each condition so that you can ensure that each `?:` are evaluated in the right order...

```
foreach ( $weight as $value )    {
    $cat = substr((string)$value->category, -1);
    $value->weight = ($cat==1 || $cat==2 || $cat==3)? 1:
        (($cat==4 || $cat==5)? 7:
        (($cat==6 || $cat==7)? 10:2));
}
```